# Not receiving e-mail sent by an iPad app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, email, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I have the following problem:

I am trying to attach a file to mail and send it via the mail form in my iPad app. I think everything goes well, the log output says the mail is sent, but I am not receiving it.

I tried everything, but still can't solve the problem.

Here is my code, please look at it and tell me if there is anything strange or wrong:

```
-(void)createCSVFile
{
    NSMutableString *csv = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"UniqueID,playerNumber,DateAndHour,Prize"];

    NSUInteger counter = [playerNumber count];
    NSLog (@"%d", counter);
    // provided all arrays are of the same length
    for (NSUInteger i=0; i < counter; i++ )
    {
        [csv appendFormat:@"\n%@,%d,%@,%@",
         [uniqueID objectAtIndex:i],
         [[playerNumber objectAtIndex:i] intValue],
         [dateAndHour objectAtIndex:i],
         [prizeWon objectAtIndex:i]
         ];
  //      NSLog (@"%@, %d, %@, %@", [uniqueID objectAtIndex:i], [[playerNumber objectAtIndex:i]intValue], [dateAndHour objectAtIndex:i], [prizeWon objectAtIndex:i]);
        // instead of integerValue may be used intValue or other, it depends how array was created
    }

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *docDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/VictoryStats.csv", docDirectory];

    NSString *outputFileName = [docDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"VictoryStats.csv"];

    NSError *error;
    BOOL res = [csv writeToFile:outputFileName atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];

    if (res)
    {
        NSLog (@"created");
    }

    if (!res) {
        NSLog(@"Error %@ while writing to file %@", [error localizedDescription], outputFileName );
    }
}


-(void)sendMail
{
    MFMailComposeViewController *mailer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    mailer.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    [mailer setSubject:@"CSV File"];
    [mailer addAttachmentData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath]
                     mimeType:@"text/csv"
                     fileName:@"VictoryStats.csv"];
    [self presentViewController:mailer animated:YES completion:NULL];

}
```

I think my code is good but seems it isn't.

Please take a look.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are u test in device or simulator?while Email window open there you seen csv file atteched.?

Comment: Please check your code in iPad device i think it will worked.

Comment: I did. I run the app on my iPad, send the mail, but not receiving it. And yes, I see the CSV file attached. I don't know what is happening.

Comment: @scourGINHO : Try to send mail without attaching file.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *docDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *filename = [docDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Product.csv"]];
    NSError *error = NULL;
    BOOL written = [csvstr writeToFile:filename atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
    if (!written)
        NSLog(@"write failed, error=%@", error);

    //CSV File
    NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[docDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Product.csv"]]];
    [mail addAttachmentData:myData mimeType:@"text/csv" fileName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Product.csv"]];
```

Comment: I didn't change anything and now works. Seems it was a bug or something like that.. Now I have another problem. Because I populate the .csv file with cyrillic words (not latin), when I open it in Excel it displays symbols instead of letters. What is wrong? I guess it related to the encoding. I have set it to NSUTF8StringEncoding.